# Android SecurityException: Permission Denial writing and sharing a file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a file, and then open a share intent to share the file.
I'm asking for runtime permission for write & read, and it seems to work aswell, but i'm getting this exception:

```
E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://package.name.provider/files/Documents/name-11-2021.csv from pid=7015, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

I create the file like this:

```
    String csv = context.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath();
    fileName = csv + "/name-" + month + "-" + year + ".csv";

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
```

and then use a writer to write to it.. later on I'm creating a share intent like so:

```
File exportFile = new File(fileName);
Uri fileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(), "package.name" + ".provider", exportFile);
requireContext().getApplicationContext().grantUriPermission("package.name", fileURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileURI);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject" + month + "-" + year);
shareIntent.setType("text/csv");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
```

and i get the exception thrown from this block, after starting activity with intent.
And ofcourse i have file provider with the authorities "${applicationId}.provider" and a 'external-files-path' configured.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
this is my provider in manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

and the XML

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-files-path name="files" path="/"/>
```

Comment: Did you set the permissions in your manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @JonR85, no permissions needed for getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: `. I'm asking for runtime permission for write & read,` Non of them is needed for getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: `requireContext().getApplicationContext().grantUriPermission("package.name", fileURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
` That makes no sense. Better remove.

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question. @blackapps its the fileName, also afaik the subject is just a title for e.g email sharing

Comment: @blackapps sorry, i mixed them up when editing out the real name.

Comment: `and i get the exception thrown from this block.` Can't you be more precise? Which statement exactly?

Comment: @blackapps after starting activity with the intent.